# Showing that $\theta$ is bijective and finding $\theta^{-1}$

Tags: functions, inverse-function

The exercise I'm doing is stated as follows:

Is the function $\theta:\scr{P}(\Bbb{Z})\rightarrow\scr{P}(\Bbb{Z})$ defined as $\theta(X)=\overline{X}$ bijective? If so, find $\theta^{-1}$

Where $\overline{X}$ denotes the complement of $X$

My reasoning is this:

Suppose $\theta(A)=\theta(A')$. This means $\overline{A}=\overline{A'}$ and therefore $A=A'$. Since $\theta(A)=\theta(A')\Rightarrow A=A'$ we can say that $\theta$ is injective.

Now suppose $B\in\scr{P}(\Bbb{Z})$. We seek some $A\in\scr{P}(\Bbb{Z})$ such that $\theta(A)=B$, which is to say $\overline{A}=B$. Solving for $A$ gives us $A=\overline{B}$, so $\theta(\overline{B})=B$, which means $\theta$ is surjective and therefore bijective.

Now to find $\theta^{-1}$ we let $Y=\overline{X}$. Switching $X$ and $Y$ and solving for $Y$ yields $Y=\overline{X}$. Therefore $\theta^{-1}(X)=\overline{X}$. This is easily verified by computing $\theta^{-1}\circ\theta$ :

$\theta^{-1}\circ\theta=\theta^{-1}(\theta(X))=\theta^{-1}(\overline{X})=\overline{\overline{X}}=X$

Is my reasoning here valid? My main concern lies in the first step where I showed that $\theta$ is injective. The entire exercise seemed a bit trivial so I'm worried that I'm overlooking something obvious. Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by $$\overline{X}$$?

Comment: sorry, that's meant to denote the complement of $X$.

Comment: Then your argument is correct; the main idea you’re using is that $$\overline{\overline{X}} = X$$.

Comment: Maybe I should’ve mentioned that you have a few notational errors, but other than that the argument is correct. In particular, $$\theta^{-1} = \theta$$.

Comment: @Aurel what are my notational errors?

Comment: Mainly where you say $$\theta^{-1} = \overline{X}$$. It should be $$\theta^{-1}(X) = \overline{X}$$. Moreover, you have to check that $$\theta \circ \theta^{-1} (X) = X$$, but this is trivial in your case.